# Magit forge: is it possible to have "upstream/master" as default when dwim diffing on a pull request?

Tags: magit

When my cursor is at a pull request in status buffer, and I press "d d", then I get the diff of `master...refs/pullreqs/XXX`. This works as intended, if my master branch is up-to-date. However, sometimes my master branch doesn't have upstream changes merged, so this diff generates a bad output.

Is it possible to have "d d" make the diff of `upstream/master...refs/pullreqs/XXX`?

I know that I can press "d r" (diff-range), then "M-n" (copy the dwim-default to mini-buffer), and then prepend "upstream/". But still, having "upstream/master" as the default would be more convenient when reviewing PRs.

Note, in my `.git/config`, I have forge/remote set as:

```
[forge]
        remote = upstream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that I saw `upstream/master`, though "not *again*" and then did not read your question properly. You can still learn something from the things I have said below, but you actually put the finger on a bug.

---

I have fixed the bug by using `remote/branch...pr` instead of `branch...pr`. `remote/branch` is much more likely to be up-to-date because pulling the pr also updates remote tracking refs but not local branches.

---

It would be better if upstream were named `origin`. That's the convention and if you don't diverge from it then a lot of things will just work and you won't have to configure them explicitly. Setting `forge.remote` for example won't be necessary anymore.

I could say a few things about you the upstream and the push-remote and how they are not the same thing but both useful. But I have done that so many times I just link to my article about that instead -> [The Two Remotes](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/The-Two-Remotes.html).

I am guessing that the reason why you don't name the upstream `origin` is that that name is already used for your fork. You can easily prevent that from happening in the future:

1. Stop cloning your fork and then adding a remote for the upstream.
2. Instead clone upstream and then add a remote for your fork. You can add your remote using the `forge-fork`. If your fork does not exist yet, then it creates it. Then it adds the fork as a remote.

If you are not in the habit of keeping `master` up-to-date, then it is better to use `origin/master` as the upstream of your feature branches instead of `master`. That way <kbd>d u</kbd> shows the changes on your feature branch without having to first check out `master`, pull and then check out `some-feature` again.

You can change the upstream using <kbd>b u</kbd>. You probably also want to set `magit-prefer-remote-upstream` (which see).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe I use names the other way around as they supposed to be. But still, I fail to see why renaming would solve my problem. If I don't have upstream's master (no matter whether it's called `upstream/master` or `origin/master`) merged in my local `master` branch, then my master is still out-of-date. So a diff between `master...PR` would still be invalid, isn't it? We should do a diff `origin/master...PR`, don't we? (I'm new to git and magit, so it's possible that I misunderstand something)

Comment: Note, I'm talking about PRs in the status buffer, which are not my feature branches. I'd like to review PRs without too much hassle. I just fetch all topics, then I'd like to simply use "d d" on a PR (without affecting my master branch). And I'm not sure whether I don't follow the conventions. I basically do exactly the same as this blog post describes: https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/01/27/using-fork-branch-git-workflow/ (the point is the bullet-point list in the beginning, and the naming convention: the fork is called `origin`, and the original repo called `upstream`)

Comment: This should be fixed now. It required changes to forge and magit so both have to be updated. It can take a few hours for the updates to become available on Melpa.

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm that, it uses `upstream/master...PR` now. It's very convenient! Magit is awesome.